# Diffraction and Fresnel Integrals

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, fresnel-integrals

**Migrated from Physics SE due to mathematical content**

I am trying to derive the intensity variation function for a single slit diffraction. [image: Diagram]

Sorry for the poor diagram...

So I decided to take the amplitudes of the waves originating from the slit on the left (wherein the variable that denotes distance within the slit is $l$) and integrate the amplitudes over the entire slit width, taking some point at a distance $x$ on the screen to achieve the resultant amplitude of the waves that strike the screen. With this function, I decided I would use the standard expression for intensity (i.e. $I=\kappa A^2)$

The amplitude for a wave originating from a point on the slit should be:
$$ y=a\sin{kr}$$
where $r$ is the distance between the point of origin on the slit and point of contact on the screen (and $k$ is the angular wave-number).
So:
$$ r^2=D^2+(x+l)^2$$
and on approximating:
$$ r\approx D+\frac{1}{2D}(x+l)^2$$
So I took the amplitude function (for the screen) as $A(x)$ and:
$$ A(x)=a\int_{-l/2}^{l/2}\sin{kD+\frac{k}{2D}(x+l)^2} dl$$
substituting $k(x+l)/2D=u$ (ignoring limits for now):
$$ A(x)=a\sqrt{\frac{2D}{k}}(\sin{kD}\int_{l_1}^{l_2}\cos{u^2}du+\cos{kD}\int_{l_1}^{l_2}\sin{u^2}du)$$
I looked these integrals up so I know that they are Fresnel Integrals, but more importantly that they are transcendental functions.

So my questions are:

1. Are my assumptions flawed?
2. Is there a flaw somewhere in the procedure?
3. If what I've done is correct, how shall I proceed?

Comment: Not that I am complaining, but this is a much more physics-oriented question than a mathematics one.  A mathematics question would have been about the validity of the approximation(s) or the properties of the Fresnel integral.  Here, we are concerned about the physical nature of the diffraction integral and what physical conditions allow for certain approximations.  It's sometimes a tough call but physics can involve math.

Comment: @RonGordon : The only reason I've migrated it here its because it didn't receive enough attention at Physics SE, and even when it did the answers were unsatisfactory. Evidently, it has been answered here in a mere fraction of the time, so the decision wasn't a poor one...

Comment: Yes, true, but I'd chalk that up to luck.  I am a physicist whose thesis was in optics and diffraction and I am here because I like to answer math questions in my spare time.  It is a rare occasion that I answer any physics/optics-related questions, although not unknown.

Comment: @RonGordon : That is indeed very lucky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) What is your basis for assuming what the amplitude of a wave originating from the slit is?  Your assumption is not clear to me and does not appear to be correct.

2) See 1).

3) What is it that you want to do?

I will derive for you an expression for the field amplitude at a point on the screen.  Let us start from first principles: the [Huygens-Fresnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) principle.  If you are unfamiliar, I suggest reading up at the link or, better yet, [Born & Wolf](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521642221).

By Huygens-Fresnel, we have

$$E(x) = -\frac{i}{\lambda} \int_{-\ell/2}^{\ell/2} dx' \frac{e^{i 2 \pi r/\lambda}}{r} \frac{1+\cos{\chi}}{2} $$

where $r = \sqrt{(x-x')^2+D^2}$ and $\chi$ is the so-called angle of inclination.  Here we will assume that, due to small angles, we may set $\chi=0$.  Further, we will expand $r$ out to second order in $(x-x')/D$ in the phase term, but to zeroth order in the amplitude term.  Thus, we may write, as the Fresnel approximation,

$$E(x) = -\frac{i}{\lambda D} e^{i 2 \pi D/\lambda} \int_{-\ell/2}^{\ell/2} dx' \, e^{i \pi (x-x')^2/(\lambda D)} $$

which we may now express in terms of Fresnel integrals as follows:

$$E(x) = -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2 \lambda D}} e^{i 2 \pi D/\lambda} \left [\mathcal{F}\left [\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda D}} \left (\frac{\ell}{2}-x \right ) \right ]-\mathcal{F}\left [-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda D}} \left (\frac{\ell}{2}+x \right ) \right ]  \right ] $$

where

$$\mathcal{F}(u) = \int_0^u du' \, e^{i \pi u'^2/2} $$

is the Fresnel integral.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've taken the standard function for a wave, i.e., $A\sin{kr-\omega t}$ and assumed an amplitude for a particular instant of time, at the screen. I took the subsequent time dependency factor as multiplicative to the rest of the sine function, which leaves, for simplicity, the expression in the post.

Comment: Your final expression is not obviously wrong.  The problem is with the assumption - it violates Huygens' principle: each point in the slit is a source of **spherical waves**, not plane waves (which is your sine function).  However, since we do not expand the amplitude in the integrand beyond the zeroth order, for the purpose of this approximation you may only be off by a scale factor.  Then again, since you use only the imaginary part of the wave, you may also be off in the phase as well.

Comment: Right, I see where I've gone wrong. Thank you! One final question: Through the amplitude function you've written at the end, how will I find the locations of maximas and minimas? Also, is it possible to relate the consequent intensity function with the usual one(expressed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction#Single-slit_diffraction))?

Comment: @PrishChakraborty: You will find the man/mins numerically, or you can take a derivative wrt $x$ and set to zero (which will not be pretty).  No, the standard Fraunhofer doffraction by a slit is a different approximation based on different assumptions.

Comment: Would you say that it is possible to arrive at the Fraunhofer intensity function by integrating the amplitudes of the spherical waves, or a similar approach in essence?

Comment: @PrishChakraborty: one gets to Fraunhofer by scaling the coordinate system on the screen according to angle.